# Home made beer in Moscow

Tags: local

I will be visiting Moscow in short time and I would like to try out some domestic beers (home brewed if possible). Can anyone recommend a place in Moscow like that and what beer should I try out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ratebeer has a [list of bars and brewpubs](http://www.ratebeer.com/places/city/moscow/0/169/). In the brewpubs you can get beer produced in the pub (or at least for the pub), which I assume is what you mean by home brewed. I really liked Durdin, which had both good food, good music, and good beer. Try their kvass! [GlavPivTorg](http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/224.html) is interesting for the historical associations, and also quite good. Their unfiltered pale lager was very good.